# Best neural network model for lot of if/else conditions

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have got a large set of data. The data has 13 parameters and those parameters depend on each other and the dependency is established by some rules.

Example:- If say parameter_one is "A", and parameter_two is "B", and there is rule stating that parameter_one==A and parameter_two==B=>parameter_three==C, then parameter_three should be C(ideally). So, basically it's a lot of if/else statements.

Now, I just have the data, and we have to make the machine learning model learn the rules, so that whenever any data comes which doesn't obeys the rules:- as in above example, if parameter_three would have been 'D' instead of 'C', then it's a violation of the rule. How can I make the model learn these rules?

Also, the rules can't be written manually since there are a lot of rules and it's not scaling.

**My try**

I thought of using an autoencoder and pass the training data through it. After that for each data, we would use the reconstruction loss to check if it's a violation case or not. However, it's overfitting and not working well on test data.

I have previously tried to use deep neural network also, but it was not helping there. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The autoencoder wasn't a bad idea. How big is the dataset? How are you encoding the features? Maybe an association rule mining algorithm like *Apriori* can help you finding the rules explicitly.

Comment: @marcoromelli The training dataset is 3 million. It has distinct data only. For validation, I have 1.5 million data. For encoding, we are converting it to one-hot encoding vector and using that. I will check out Apriori algorithm.

Comment: With such a big dataset overfitting shouldn't be a problem. Try maybe tuning the autoencoder architecture. If you post some code people can help you more easily.

Comment: No, we have removed the duplicate rows. All training rows are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Association Rule Mining algorithms like Apriori or FP-Growth to generate the frequent item sets.

From the frequent item sets you can generate Association rules.

Once you have the association rules, you can assign a weight to each rule (or use some parameter like confidence/lift of the rule).

When you want to test it on a new data entry, do weighted summing (if the new entry satisfies a rule, use the rule's weight to calculate the score/sum for the new entry).

If the generated score for the new entry is greater than a chosen threshold, you can say the new entry passes the preset rules otherwise it's in violation of the rules.

Weighted summing gives you flexibility to assign importance to association rules. You can also do this, if new entry does not satisfy even one of the association rules, then it is in violation of preset rules.